# Error mapping data type Oracle and C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an table with `ID NUMBER(18)` and I have a class with properties `public Int64 ID { get; set; }` to mapping ID form C# vs Oracle.

My table definition

[image]

But I have an error when I get max ID like this:

1. Run query

   ```
   SELECT MAX(ID) ID FROM MYTABLE
   ```

   The system throw an error:

   > "Object of type 'System.Decimal' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int64'."
2. But when I run query like this:

   ```
   SELECT ID FROM(
                   SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY ID DESC
                 ) WHERE ROWNUM =1
   ```

   It OK.

I don't know why (1) throw error, and why (2) done?

What is the difference between datatype (1) and (2)?

Comment: @lad2025: The query 1 and 2 return the same value, why 1 error and 2 done?

Comment: Please post your table definition. It looks like problem with column metadata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possible scenario 1:**

I guess that you have `NULL` values in table (so your both queries are not equivalent):

```
SELECT MAX(ID) ID FROM T_00_RQMM  -- aggregate func ignore NULLS
```

But:

```
SELECT ID FROM(SELECT ID FROM T_00_RQMM ORDER BY ID DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;  
-- NULL is the max value
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=00efd12df5cf8aff6f404986f0aed7b3)**

Anyway you should try mapping:

```
using System.Numerics;
...
public BigInteger ID { get; set; }
```

---

**EDIT:**

**Possible scenario 2:**

It may be problem with data type (then use explicit `CAST`):

```
SELECT CAST(MAX(ID) AS NUMBER(18,0)) ID FROM T_00_RQMM
```

**[DBFiddle Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aff91ae525f49b500c59e309c0342662)**

Full demo:

```
CREATE TABLE T_00_RQMM (ID NUMBER(18,0));
INSERT INTO T_00_RQMM VALUES(NULL);
INSERT INTO T_00_RQMM VALUES(100);

CREATE TABLE t1 AS SELECT MAX(ID) ID FROM T_00_RQMM;

CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT ID FROM(SELECT ID FROM T_00_RQMM ORDER BY ID DESC) 
                                  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

CREATE TABLE t3 AS SELECT CAST(MAX(ID) AS NUMBER(18,0)) ID FROM T_00_RQMM;


SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_PRECISION, DATA_SCALE
FROM all_tab_cols
where table_name in ('T1', 'T2', 'T3')
ORDER BY Table_name;
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_PRECISION | DATA_SCALE |
+------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
| T1         | ID          | null           | null       |
| T2         | ID          | 18             | 0          |
| T3         | ID          | 18             | 0          |
+------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: No, I has been check carefully, It not null. The query 1, and 2 return the same value. But I don't  know why 1 throw error

Comment: @HongVanVit Ok, it looks like metadata problem when using `MAX` datatype is `NUMBER` and not `NUMBER(18)`